# Linking SP 2013 with Wordpress - Search engine

Tags: search, search-results

I have a Sharepoint 2013 installation on a server, that runs our intranet.
We plan to use a Wordpress installation to blog (the existing functionality in SP does not suit our needs, especially on the "theme" side).

We'd like the existing (and quite good) search engine on our intranet to be able to crawl and index these future Wordpress blog. This way when a user perform a search on the intranet, he would be able to see both intranet and Wordpress results.

Is there a way or a workaround to do that ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just add your Wordpress site as a Content Source of type Web and create a crawl schedule that suits your publishing schedule.

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for your answer and my apologises for the delay.

I'll try this next week and keep you posted.

Thanks again !